# Orchard issue with added module

Tags: routes, orchardcms

I have another issue with Orchard. 
I have created new module - HelloWorld (as in the Orchard web site tutorial)
One thing I do diffrent is that I move my project outside the Orchard and I create new solution where I have added this module project. I set post-build to copy my project to Orchard.Web\Modules by robocopy:

```
  robocopy "$(ProjectDir)..\$(ProjectName)" "$(ProjectDir)..\..\Orchard\src\Orchard.Web\Modules\HelloWorld" /XO /NJH /E

  if errorlevel 4 goto Fail
  if errorlevel 0 goto End

  :Fail
  echo FILECOPY for $(ProjectName) FAILED
  exit 1
  :End
  echo FILECOPY for $(ProjectName) COMPLETED OK
  exit 0
```

After my module is copied I try to access page with my module and get 404 response.

In Routes.cs I have

```
public IEnumerable<RouteDescriptor> GetRoutes()
    {
        return new[]
            {
                new RouteDescriptor
                    {
                        Priority = 20,
                        Route =
                            new Route(
                            "HelloWorld",
                            new RouteValueDictionary
                                {
                                    { "area", "HelloWorld" }, { "controller", "Home" }, { "action", "Index" } 
                                },
                            new RouteValueDictionary(),
                            new RouteValueDictionary { { "area", "HelloWorld" } },
                            new MvcRouteHandler())
                    }
            };
    }
```

After opening Routes.cs in Orchard.Web\Modules\HelloWorld and making any change (ex: adding space or changing comment) and save Routes.cs my modules is starting to work. 
Have anyone any idea why my module is not working after copying it to Modules folder ?

Comment: Dynamic compilation. Why would you make everything more complicated by moving the module out of the site?

Comment: Yes I know, but I thought that after I copy project with updates, Orchard is compiled dynamicly. I move my project outside Orchard solution because I am focusd on developing my module and for me vs is working faster with one project than ~60 of Orchard.

Comment: That doesn't require taking it out. Just open that project directly, or create a separate solution. Really, there is no good reason to do that.

Comment: Agreed with Bertrand. C+P the Orchard SLN, and remove the projects you don't want in there, It will make everything a million times easier.